# How can I tell if something is in weapons range?

Tags: fallout-4

Is there any visual indicator or a way of measuring how far away a target is?  That way I can see if I'm outside of my sniper rifles optional range before shooting.

Comment: Have you tried using the VATS with a sniper? I haven't myself, but I know with other weapons and using the VATS, I would get better percentages for critical hits depending on how far away I was from the target. That _might_ give a good representation on distance.

Comment: C-dizzle if you can figure out what distance maps to how far I'll give you a gold star :D. My main concern is that being out of optimal range drops me damage by up to half

Answer (score 1):

The only way I've seen to determine how effective an attack might be is through using VATS. When you've selected a target, you will see their current health. Part of that health bar will be darkened or blinking. (Don't have the game in front of me now, so I'm not certain which.) This indicates how much damage your attack would do if successful. It appears to take into account things like bonuses for head-shots and sneak attacks, so I expect range is factored in as well.

Unless a weapon has some sort of special feature on it (such as a range-finding scope; I haven't completed the game yet, so I'm not sure whether or not these might exist), or someone makes an appropriate mod for your platform, VATS is probably the best you can do. After using VATS with certain weapons for awhile, you might be able to make reasonably accurate guesses by yourself. But that's about it.

Comment: Yes, you can definitely hit targets that are further away that VATS wouldn't normally allow, so I share your belief in that. It could also simply be a Perception thing.

Comment: If you take a look at the formulas for damage in fallout 4, you'll see that any target outside of your weapons range drops off to a certain point: fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Damage_Resistance

Comment: In particular, the part about range multiplier:  RangeMulti is

    1.0, when inside WeaponRange
    0.5 to 1.0, when between WeaponRange and 2xWeaponRange
    0.5, when outside 2xWeaponRange

Comment: that's what led me to this question in the first place actually, I'd like to know if I'm in or outside of my weapon range for optimal damage

Comment: @z' Ah, got it. So far, without mods, I'm pretty sure the only reliable indicator available to you is VATS. With some experience, you might learn to "eyeball" it for your favorite weapons.

Comment: To be fair though, it seems to me that the "targeting range" of VATS is independent of the weapon you have. I had a double-barrel shotgun equipped, and VATS allowed me to shoot at a target pretty far away, but they took 0 damage because it's outside the weapon's range.

Comment: @TimS. Did VATS give you any indication that damage would actually be done?

Comment: I always assumed that the numbers on the body parts were the chance you had of actually hitting that body part, and the numbers were definitely not zero. I just know that after a full barrage of shots, no damage was done at all. (Aside from that, I really don't know for sure.)

Answer (score -2):

I use Vats if I have a target that has around 10 to 10% chance to hit then I know I am in range for the weapon I am holding.So far this has worked for me, I do hope that a rangefinder mod comes out one day.

Comment: You can hit things that are far away enough that doesn't trigger vats