# Weapon-Range: How does it affect gameplay?

Tags: fallout-4

This question may sound stupid at the first glance, but I wonder what impact this number has. If you have a pistol with a range of 60, will VATS only activate if there are enemies within that range? And what happens if you shoot at someone to far away? Does the bullet begin to sink (would be a weird type of ballistic) or does it simply vanish?

All I can say is that there wasn't a single enemy until now that I couldn't hit even over the biggest distances, if it wasn't for the accuracy.

Comment: Usually range indicates damage falloff. I'm not sure how it affects VATS, but I do know it's line-of-sight based so range doesn't change anything with activating it. But the damage and maybe accuracy are affected by the range stat.

Comment: It definitely affects damage, as related in [this answer](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/244231/108003) and its comments.

Comment: the vats range is determined by the perception skill if im not wrong

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it affects the detection range of the VATS.
You could try to use a wide ranged weapon and spot a far enemy and then change to a short ranged weapon. There shouldn't be a difference.
VATS is also available if you don't have a weapon in your hand - or if you have a meele weapon.

It should only be an indicator for the VATS damage and accuracy.

Comment: +1, I think this is right, actually. I keep forgetting to do the test mentioned to double-check VATS detection range.

Comment: This is correct, if you try to shoot with a pistol at long range, your hit chance will just be 2% or so..